# Compiler thinks T is not a byte array even though it is

Tags: c#, .net

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
{
    Encoding.Default.GetChars(ts.ToArray());
}
```

Now I know that there is no way this won't work. The variable "TS" was received with a type argument. And with the if statement above, I know that this has to be a byte array. But, the compiler doesn't know that. So it thinks that I am converting a variable of an "unknown" type to byte[] which will give an error. And thus it doesn't work.

So what do I do? Is there anyway to tell the compiler that "T" is of type "byte[]" and that it can be converted to a char array?

I tried `T=byte[];` but that gives an error saying that "T" is not a variable

```
//the rest of my code. I was gonna use this to make a disposable list. I was mostly doing this to learn OOP that's all
        private class DisposableList<T> : List<T>, IDisposable
        {

            public static explicit operator Array(DisposableList<T> ts)
            {

                object[] e = { };
                return e;
            }



            public static implicit operator char[](DisposableList<T> ts, string EncodingPar)
            {
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
                {
                    Encoding.Default.GetChars(ts.ToArray());
                }
                else
                {
                    char[] vs = ts.ToString().ToCharArray();
                    return vs;
                }

            }
            //public static explicit operator char[](disposablelist<t> ts)
            //{

            //}
            private T[] ReturnArray()
            {
                return ToArray();
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose();
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
```

Edit 2 & 5: Thanks to @Dmitry I now know that I just had to do

```
if (ts is byte[] Array)
```

Edit 3: Shortest code needed to reproduce

```
            public static implicit operator char[](DisposableList<T> ts, string EncodingPar)
            {
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
                {
                    Encoding.Default.GetChars(ts.ToArray());
                }
                else
                {
                    char[] vs = ts.ToString().ToCharArray();
                    return vs;
                }

            }
```

Desired behaviour: The compiler should think that T is byte. With the above code, I can be certain that type of T is equal to the type of byte. The compiler is not and it refuses to compile the code. This was solved by doing something like this

```
if (ts is byte[] array) {
//my code here
}
```

instead of

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
{
    //My code here
}
```

Edit 4: Oh and I've programmed this in C#.

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve], you haven't got a complete example here. There's no clear relationship between T and ts.

Comment: Where go got `ts` from? Is it a generic method parameter of type `T`? Try: `Byte[] tsArray =  (byte[])Convert.ChangeType(ts, typeof(byte[]));`

Comment: I'd hazard to guess you're looking for `(byte[]) (object) ts`, but, per Mason, an MRE would help both us and future readers.

Comment: @mason: it is if `ts` is of type `T`, with `T` an unconstrained generic parameter, as otherwise the compiler will (rightfully) reject the cast since it would not be correct for a value type. That said, this is all speculation based on what I think the missing code is.

Comment: Probably is should be something like this: `if (ts is byte[] array) {Encoding.Default.GetChars(array);}`

Comment: Just guessing here, did you actually mean to say `typeof(byte))` (and not `typeof(byte[]))`).

Comment: Oh yeah. I'll just make the edit

Comment: I've made my edit is it still a little unclear? Please help on as to what I've said wrong